# Why does the second subscriber receive all the elements in RxSwift?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I currently have the following code. Both listeners are able to receive all 5 emitted values.

However, I am confused, shouldn't the second listener miss the first few elements?

```swift
import RxSwift
import Foundation

let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

let mainObservable = Observable<String>.create { observer in
    observer.onNext("Element 1")
    observer.onNext("Element 2")
    observer.onNext("Element 3")
    observer.onNext("Element 4")
    observer.onNext("Element 5")
    observer.onCompleted()
    return Disposables.create()
}

mainObservable.subscribe(onNext: { element in
    print("listener1 received: \(element)")
}, onCompleted: {
    print("listener1 completed")
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)

// The following prints out immediately
// listener1 received: Element 1
// listener1 received: Element 2
// listener1 received: Element 3
// listener1 received: Element 4
// listener1 received: Element 5
// listener1 completed

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
    mainObservable.subscribe(onNext: { element in
        print("listener2 received: \(element)")
    }, onCompleted: {
        print("listener2 completed")
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}

// The following prints out after 2 seconds
// listener2 received: Element 1 (why am I getting this one?)
// listener2 received: Element 2 (why am I getting this one?)
// listener2 received: Element 3 (why am I getting this one?)
// listener2 received: Element 4
// listener2 received: Element 5
// listener2 completed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Both subscribers will and should receive all the elements.

To understand why you need only look at this part of the code:

```
let mainObservable = Observable<String>.create { observer in
    observer.onNext("Element 1")
    observer.onNext("Element 2")
    observer.onNext("Element 3")
    observer.onNext("Element 4")
    observer.onNext("Element 5")
    observer.onCompleted()
    return Disposables.create()
}
```

That code creates an `Observable`. And it says, "whenever an observer subscribes to me, I will send it five next events and a completed event."

You have two observers subscribing to it, so each observer receives five next events and a completed event.

Most Observables work this way, they are called "cold" observables which basically means they don't share side effects between observers, each observer gets its own set.

There are a select few that are "hot", which means that they *do* share side effects. An example of these sorts of observables would be things like UI events.

You can learn more by searching for information about hot vs cold observables. One very good, if somewhat advanced, article about the subject is here: https://www.davesexton.com/blog/post/Hot-and-Cold-Observables.aspx

A good video on the subject is here: https://egghead.io/lessons/rxjs-demystifying-cold-and-hot-observables-in-rxjs